# Disable "Segmentation fault/access violation in generated code"?

Tags: haskell, ghc, ffi

We're using FFI to call potentially unsafe C functions. Sometimes bugs in such functions made our Haskell code that is using them to popup "Segmentation fault/access violation in generated code" message in the console. Under Windows I cannot do anything with that. I cannot see the source of the problem.

Is there a way to disable that message so the unhandled exception propagate to the OS, so we could catch it and see which C-compiled DLL on the call chain gives the error and where there?

Comment: Possibly relevant: [#13108 Improve poor Access Violation reporting on Windows](https://ghc.haskell.org/trac/ghc/ticket/13108) ([committed](https://git.haskell.org/ghc.git/commitdiff/c13151e5ac774d38d7c5a807692851022c18fe6b)).

Comment: Wow, great! Thanks!